# Is this question on-topic for SO?

Tags: discussion

I sort of think it is, a bunch of people don't, but a mod thinks it is.  So I dunno, is it?

[Why should I use git instead of traditional TFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27515800/why-should-i-use-git-instead-of-traditional-tfs)

Comment: I didn't say "a bunch of mods".  Read carefully.  :-)

Comment: Note that *neither* mod/employee who commented reopened with their binding vote, so they didn't feel *that* strongly that it was a good question here.

Comment: @jez ok fair enough, but the "mod" that said it was on-topic is not a mod, you should read the comments to your own question more carefully :-)

Comment: For the record, your [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27515800/why-should-i-use-git-instead-of-traditional-tfs#comment43461855_27515800) seems to suggest you think your question is on topic simply because there is an existing similar question.  It has been said numerous times that an existing questions does not automatically make a new question magically on-topic.  The original question was asked in 2009 when the guidelines were much different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not a great question. As Gabe notes, it's kinda fuzzy - but more importantly, it asks two very different things:

1. Which of these two things should **I** use based on my specific requirements and experience?
2. How do these two things differ?

In theory, #1 could be a reasonable question... If your needs were very specific and folks could be expected to provide concrete answers explaining how each version control system would meet (or fail to meet) those needs. But your needs aren't very specific. Which is probably why you pivoted into #2 toward the end of your question...

And #2 is a reasonable question. Somewhat broad, but not, I think, excessively so. It's also a duplicate - so I went ahead and marked it as such.

Answer (score 2):

No, its a complete opinion question.  Although the answer is "Because visual source safe is a non-functional relic of the deeper realms of hell, and is only theoretically slightly better than using .zip and .zip.bak files".

Comment: TFS isn't Visual Source Safe.

Comment: Your answer shows why we don't allow such questions. Its just flame-bait for those who don't like Git, or TFS, or both, or Source Control in general.

Comment: No, its the rebranding of it because the original was known to regularly corrupt and lose data.  After their first version, why would you ever trust one of their products with your data again?  I'd rather use CVS.  I'd rather use RCS.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET That was actually done on purpose, although it happens that is my actual opinion on the matter as well :)

Comment: You accomplished your purpose beautifully then :) Just for the record, I've yet to lose data with modern TFS, though I'm not a *heavy* user.

Comment: I refuse to use modern TFS.  I have lost data on VSS (while working as a MS contractor for a 3 month stint!) as late as 2010.

Comment: I don't really understand the opinion based closes these days. Lots of people discovered SO through them.

Comment: TFS is not VSS. Unfortunately, Microsoft kept VSS available for waaaaaay too long, and then made moving to TFS too hard/expensive when they finally did release it. So there's little goodwill toward it for those of us who suffered under VSS, @Bradley.